# BCrypt (blowfish) password for AES 256 (Rijndael) encrypted text

Tags: java, security, encryption, hash, aes

I decided to try BCrypt for hashing key for AES256 (Rijndael/CBC).

Problem is that AES256 key has to be 32 bytes long. BCrypt key is 60 bytes long and naturally always different. Maybe pretty hard and long week is to blame but I am not able to see how could I use a key hashed with BCrypt in combination with AES256. Am I just tired and blind or there is no way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Uh, take the first 32-bytes and discard the rest?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to hash something (like a password) and use that as an AES Key?

I'm not familiar with BCrypt, but SHA-256 would create a hash that is the same size as an AES 256 key. Or if your bent on using BCrypt you could just read the first 32 bytes of that hash and discard the rest.

Comment: I obviously had a mental breakdown :). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should ever discard bytes from cryptography calculations, because those bytes are supposed to support the other bytes you kept - discarding some weakens the output.

Comment: It depends on the context. You also discard bytes of the hash in ECDSA and it's fine. But I agree that you should be knowing exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a secure [Key Derivation Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). Truncating the bytes as suggested in the comments works sometimes, but it always depends on the context, so don't do it if you're not absolutely sure about it.

Truncating won't work anyway in situations where you need to "stretch" your input, it's also where the most mistakes are made. If you can't create your key using a secure random generator, typically, what you want to do is transform some non-random input (e.g. password) into something worth as key material. Obviously, the entropy of non-random data is normally not good enough for the purpose.

Look into [PKCS#5](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2127) and use its PBKDF2 if you want to transform passwords into arbitrary-length keys for AES or any other symmetric encryption algorithm.